# Rails 4: update form field displayed value based on value selected in previous field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following form

```
<div class="calendar_details">
  <%= f.label :target_age_lower_limit, "AGE (LOWER LIMIT)" %>
  <%= f.select :target_age_lower_limit, (0..99) %>
</div>
<div class="calendar_details">
  <%= f.label :target_age_upper_limit, "AGE (UPPER LIMIT)" %>
  <%= f.select :target_age_upper_limit, (0..99) %>
</div>
```

Which renders the following HTML code:

```
<div class="calendar_details">
      <label for="calendar_target_age_lower_limit">AGE (LOWER LIMIT)</label>
      <select name="calendar[target_age_lower_limit]" id="calendar_target_age_lower_limit"><option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      [...]
      <option value="99">99</option></select>
</div>

<div class="calendar_details">
      <label for="calendar_target_age_upper_limit">AGE (UPPER LIMIT)</label>
      <select name="calendar[target_age_upper_limit]" id="calendar_target_age_upper_limit"><option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      [...]
      <option value="99">99</option></select>
</div>
```

Currently, a user can select an age lower limit of 34 and an age upper limit of 25 if he wants to, which makes no sense in terms of business logic.

I would like to implement a JS function that will:

- Freeze the upper limit options that are smaller than the value selected in the lower limit field (if the lower limit field was filled first)
- Freeze the lower limit options that are bigger than the value selected in the upper limit field (if the upper limit field was filled first)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use a slider like this one http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider_range .

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This sounds like a good idea. Any recommendation to implement it in a Rails form?

Comment: The problem with a  slider like that one is that you have to now include Jquery Mobile.

Comment: Here is an example on achieving what you want: http://www.codeoncall.com/disable-drop-down-list-items-based-on-another-drop-down-selection/ . You don't have to change the attribute to disabled manually, you can do it in a loop with a condition.